# Использование переменных в .properties

Tags: java, properties

Есть `.properties` файл в нем лежат пути:

```
path1=doc/1.txt
path2=src/2.png
```

И есть корень который ведет в папку где лежат `doc/1` и `src/2`

```
root=/user/pavel/Document/
```

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы я мог только в одном месте менять корень. На пример:

```
root=/user/pavel/Document
path1=${root}/doc/1.txt
path2=${root}/src/2.png
```

Как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если проект собирается maven'ом то можно сделать так:

в `pom.xml` добавить следующее:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <custom.property>property-value</custom.property>
  </properties>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>file.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
<project>
```

тогда если `file.properties` содержит шаблон, на примере такого:

```
prop.name = value of my prop is ${custom.property}
```

после сборки или выполнения команды: `prepare-resources`

в дублированном файле находящемся в `target/`, окажется строка:

```
prop.name = value of my prop is property-value
```

Помимо этого, во избежание потенциальных проблем с кодировками, необходимо указать настройки idea следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и если значение `properties` на русском, то будет необходимо применить метод вроде этого:

```
public String encodeToUTF8(String stringToEncode) {
    byte[] stringBytes = stringToEncode.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    return new String(stringBytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если поискать на SO, то можно найти этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263929/regarding-application-properties-file-and-environment-variable)

Из него видно, что java не парсит переменные сама, это надо делать за нее.

Для переменных окружения эта можно сделать так:

```
    /*
 * Returns input string with environment variable references expanded, e.g. $SOME_VAR or ${SOME_VAR}
 */
private String resolveEnvVars(String input)
{
    if (null == input)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // match ${ENV_VAR_NAME} or $ENV_VAR_NAME
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}|\\$(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input); // get a matcher object
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()){
        String envVarName = null == m.group(1) ? m.group(2) : m.group(1);
        String envVarValue = System.getenv(envVarName);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, null == envVarValue ? "" : envVarValue);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```